# Can you Perform "Remote" Deployment of a .war File in Tomcat Manager

Tags: tomcat

I have been able to deploy my web application here: http://localhost:8081/Tutorial/

I have to get this web application set up via remote deployment is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Comment: This is a Java web application

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen straight from the manager page?

Comment: I'd just SCP the war file, but it should be doable from the manager as well. Security becomes an issue though if you expose the manager to the outside.

Comment: I know how to fix that security issue.

Comment: This article has a good section about hardening the Tomcat Manager app: https://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-security

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen thank you, sir.